# window.location.reload(true) will load from the server but doesn't invalidate the cache?

Tags: reactjs, version, updates, browser-cache, reload

My problem is this:

When I release a new version of my single page app, the backend will send a message to the frontend that the minimum version is for example v1.1.

If the client at that point is less than 1.1 (say 1.0) it will display a button to reload the page to update the version.

When the user presses the button we call `window.location.reload(true)` to fetch index.html from the server.

This works great! The problem is, if the user closes that window and then loads the url again, it grabs the cached version which is still 1.0.

How can I invalidate the browser cache for v1.0? Or is there another method to make sure that the user will never see 1.0 again and only see 1.1?

Thanks!